# Python 2.7 Tkinter Take Photo with CV2

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, webcam

I want to make a Python 2.7 Tkinter take webcam photo but I can't arrived at the end of a problem: my program don't want to read a variable and execute it. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

width, height = 800, 600    #Initialisation of webcam size
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)   #Type of Capture

takePicture = 0 #My variable

lmain = tk.Label()  #The Tk widget of webcam
lmain.pack()    #Pack option to see it
screenTake = tk.Button(text='ScreenShot' ) , command = TakePictureC) #The button for take picture
screenTake.pack()   #Pack option to see it

def TakePictureC(): #There is the change of the variable

    takePicture  = takePicture + 1 #Add "1" to the variable

def show_frame(): #CV2 webcam parameters
_, frame = cap.read()
frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
lmain.imgtk = imgtk
lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
lmain.after(10, show_frame)

if takePicture == 1: #My option for take the image
    img.save("test.png") #Save the instant image
    takePicture  = takePicture - 1 #Remove "1" to the variable

show_frame() #CV2 show the webcam module
root = tk.Tk()                                  #basic parameters
root.bind('<Escape>', lambda e: root.quit())
root.title( "title" )
root.mainloop()                                 #end of the program
```

Thank's for help and have a good week!(Sorry for my very bad english, I'm a french student :/ )

My error message:

C:\Users***\Desktop\Programmations\Python-Programming\PyStoMo>

python    TestWeb1.p y

Traceback (most recent call last): File "TestWeb1.py", line 12, in  screenTake = tk.Button(text='ScreenShot' , command = TakePictureC)#The butt on for take picture

NameError: name 'TakePictureC' is not defined

Comment: So... Are you getting an error message, or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you're seeing an error message ("traceback"), you should show it in full (copy-and-paste it).

This line:

```
screenTake = tk.Button(text='ScreenShot' ) , command = TakePictureC) #The button for take picture
```

has too many ')'. It should be:

```
screenTake = tk.Button(text='ScreenShot', command = TakePictureC) #The button for take picture
```

Next, inside a function, if you assign to a name, it will assume that the name is local unless you say otherwise, so when you try to run this function:

```
def TakePictureC(): #There is the change of the variable

    takePicture  = takePicture + 1 #Add "1" to the variable
```

it'll raise a NameError.

That should be:

```
def TakePictureC(): #There is the change of the variable
    global takePicture
    takePicture  = takePicture + 1 #Add "1" to the variable
```

Finally, the body of the function 'show_frame' should be indented.

EDIT:

Your traceback says:

```
NameError: name 'TakePictureC' is not defined
```

That's because the line:

```
screenTake = tk.Button(text='ScreenShot', command = TakePictureC)
```

says to call TakePictureC when the bottom is clicked, but TakePictureC hasn't been defined yet.

Comment: I have do all modification and the console say: C:\Users\***\Desktop\Programmations\Python-Programming\PyStoMo>python TestWeb1.p
y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestWeb1.py", line 12, in <module>
    screenTake = tk.Button(text='ScreenShot' , command = TakePictureC) #The butt
on for take picture
NameError: name 'TakePictureC' is not defined